# How to hide url of the embedded mov files in drupal using swftools?

Tags: drupal, flowplayer, embedded-media

How can I hide or obfuscate the url of the embedded mov files in drupal using swftools and flowplayer 3 as the video player. 
I tried using SWFObject2 but infact it outputs the url very clearly.

The site is basically a online video selling site, so I want to be able to prevent users to download the videos on their computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could encrypt the video name, so instead of `www.yoursite.com/sites/all/files/myvideo.flv` you have `www.yoursite.com/sites/all/files/fue8rughht94rjfieiwkdnd9tzdhezfh3993`. This simply gets stored into the database and when called, you need to decrypt it.

Alternativly, you can have a singe entry file like access that takes the video name you want to show to the user like `access?vid=myvideo.flv`. This way, you can check more easily if the user has the permission to download the video.

I know this is not very Drupal related but this would require a custom approach anyway.

Comment: ok, how can I achieve file name encryption and decryption, maybe I'll write a module for that.

Comment: Just google it. There are many tutorials and how-tos available. A good place to start is http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php. Be sure to alreays read through the comments for great snippets.